# What is the underlying logic behind printf function?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

Recently, I am playing around with C to test different things.

```
printf("%d", 0.4);
```

would print -1717986918.

I understand that this must be related to the binary representation of a floating-point number. However, after using some online resources to convert 0.4 into a float the binary representation does not match with -171986918. Please explain what really happened behind this piece of code.

PS: I am using gcc compiler and running it on Windows 64 bit.

Comment: `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(double)` (which `0.4` probably is) have a different number of bytes (most likely).

Comment: @FiddlingBits Thank you, apparently this conversion omits the first 16 bits of the double value. One follow-up question, would it be safe to say that C uses double as the "default" float type then?

Comment: The constant `0.4` has type `double`.  As such, it is not properly matched with the `%d` directive, with the result that your `printf` call has **undefined behavior**.  What "actually happens" depends on details of your implementation of `printf`, and possibly on other factors as well.  This is not a useful detail to study, beyond learning the lesson that you must properly type match your `printf` arguments with the format string.  Whatever specifics you might figure out would not be reliably transferrable.

Comment: Note that if you enabled warnings (e.g. `gcc -Wall`), the `printf` statement would be flagged by the compiler.

Comment: Some systems — macOS Mojave 10.14.6 is one, but I believe Linux x86/64 is another — have an ABI that passes integers and doubles in different sets of registers. That means if you don't have the compiler set to fussy, you get the "correct" result from `printf("Integer: %4d; double: %13.6g\n", 3.141592654, 9876);` — that is, it produces "Integer: 9876; double: 3.14159`, give or take some spaces.  That's because when `printf()` processes the `%d`, it pulls the first integer out of the integer registers, and when it processes `%13.6g`, it pulls the first double out of the floating point registers.

Comment: You can't rely on that behaviour.  Most historical systems would not behave like that.  But (at least some of) the x86/64 ABIs in use lend themselves to this abuse.

Comment: [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) also requires the conversion specifiers be the correct type for the arguments -- so the just because compiling with non-fussy options may allow it to work sometimes -- doesn't mean it is well-formed code `:)` Output of `-1717986918` likely means the `RSI` register is uninitialized.

Comment: @FiddlingBits without any suffixes then a floating-point literal is always `double`. `f` and `L` make it `float` and `long double` respectively

Comment: Next time, compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that this must be related to the binary representation

No, it is undefined behavior (UB).

---

`"%d"` with a `double` does not match.

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.  C17dr § 7.21.6.1 9

The output and behavior is not defined (UB) by the language. Anything may happen.

---

On some systems, the UB might see a portion of the binary pattern interpreted as an `int`.

On another systems, `int` and `double` are passed in different ways and the output seen is based on garbage.

On another system or just another day, *bad* things happen.

It is all undefined behaviors (UB).

---

> explain what really happened

To get an idea of what might have happened in OP's machine, use hexadecimal outputs.

```
printf("%x\n", (unsigned) -1717986918);  // UB to print a negative  `int` with `"%x"`
printf("%a\n", 0.4);

9999999a
0x1.999999999999ap-2
```

So it looks like the least significant 4 bytes of `0.4` significand were interpreted as the `int`.
**Still UB**.  Anything may happen.